# Issues with javascript click behaviour in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am currently working on a chrome extension to automate a manual task to allocate time to a VR machine setup on Springboard VR.

I have come across an issue with my scripts where the final button press in the process does not seem to trigger to correct response on the website.

The process simply clicks through a series of prompts (with a time delay between each click to allow for loading) and sets a time extension on the VR station (usually 15 mins). All steps execute successfully and no errors are thrown, but the time does not get added. If however I remove only the last click and then click manually the time is added to the station.

Also manually running the `$("button.submit.extend")[0].click()` in the chrome console triggers the correct behaviour. I am at a loss as to why this is the case...

I am running the script below as a content script

```
    "content_scripts" : [{
    "matches": ["https://monitor.springboardvr.com/*"],
    "js": ["lib/jquery.js", "js/time.js"]
}]
```

[image: monitor.springboardvr.com]

```js
// runs the frontend process to add time to a given station
// selected station is an index, timeExt is minutes and clickDelay is milliseconds
function runScript(selectedStation, timeExt, clickDelay) {

    var addTimeBtn = $("button[title='Add Time']")[selectedStation];
    addTimeBtn.click();

    setTimeout(function() {
        
        var customTimeBtn = $("button:contains('+Custom')")[0];
        customTimeBtn.click();

        setTimeout(function() {
            var timeInput = $("input[name='minutes']");
            timeInput.val(timeExt);

            setTimeout(function() {
                
                var extendTimeBtn = $("button.submit.extend")[0];
                console.log(extendTimeBtn);
                extendTimeBtn.click();

            }, 3000);

        }, clickDelay);

    }, clickDelay)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's because `.click()` only runs code in the same execution context, but a content script runs in *isolated world*. You can try `element.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true}))` or [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879)

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned. I am running the code above in a content script

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Comment: @Rob I believe it makes sense for me to do so here so I can show the relevant DOM section as well as provide a visual indicator as to what I am trying to click (the circled button). It provides context to the code that I have provided.

Comment: From the Help Center: "Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly."

Comment: @Rob short of copying the entire DOM this would provide no real benefit. And since the site is a 3rd party site, its not exactly ideal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was being caused by Vue.js which was in use on the site. Vue was not able to detect changes in the input fields. In order to fix this I manually triggered a HTML event to force Vue to update its data model, this fixed the issue.

```
// creates a html event to force Vue.js to update its model
function createHtmlEvent() {

    var event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
    event.initEvent('input', true, true);

    return event;
}

function allocateTime() {
    ....
    var event = createHtmlEvent();
    timeInput[0].dispatchEvent(event);
}
```